# Capture attributes in XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to capture the attribute "description" in this XML:

```
<ProductoModel xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApi.Models">
<descripcion>descripcion 1</descripcion>
<fecha_registro>2016-03-01</fecha_registro>
<id_producto>1</id_producto>
<id_proveedor>1</id_proveedor>
<nombre_producto>producto 1</nombre_producto>
<precio>200</precio>
</ProductoModel>
```

My Code :

```
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.LoadXml(content);

    XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
    manager.AddNamespace("MYNS", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebApi.Models");

    XmlNode node = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("MYNS:ProductoModel", manager);

    MessageBox.Show(node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("descripcion").Value);
```

The problem is I can not capture the attribute "descripcion" and get the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

As I can capture the required attribute?

Comment: `<descripcion>` is an **Element** not an **Attribute**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<descripcion>` is not attribute. It is element.

You can get any element (or attribute) with a single xpath query.

```
XmlNode node = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/MYNS:ProductoModel/MYNS:descripcion", manager);

MessageBox.Show(node.InnerText);
```

Note the character `/` at the beginning of the xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want another easy way operate XML, check [this](https://github.com/631320085/XmlObject) out. This is a little tool for xml operate, it's much easier to use and understand than XmlNode.